# Is there a way to repeat a filter-branch operation on any new commits?

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I have a large repository containing several projects. I need to make another repository containing only a subset of these projects. I can achieve this using `git filter-branch` on a clone of the repository, as described in answers to other questions, like this:

```
<clone the source repository>
git filter-branch --tag-name-filter cat --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch --quiet <project1> <project2>' --prune-empty -- --all
rm -rf refs/original
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --aggressive --prune=now
```

which works fine, but the problem is that it takes over an hour to perform this operation (about 4000 commits are filtered).  Since I need to do this regularly, as new commits are made to the source repository, it's not an ideal solution.

Is there a way to achieve some sort of 'incremental' filter-branch, which is triggered when new commits are made to the source, and updates (rather than completely recreating) the filtered repository by only filtering the new commits and merging them to the previously filtered output?

(Because of the code layout, and for historical reasons, it's not practical to separate the projects out into their own individual repositories.)

Comment: Yes, I can certainly use a hook to detect when the filter operation is needed, but I'm more interested in whether there is a way to just filter the new commit, rather than having to filter the whole repository again.

Comment: Afaik you can, to some extend, change the commit in the hook. Never looked too deply into it though.

Comment: I am running into the exact same problem. Any help would be appreciated.